# Vue.js Changing props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm a bit confused about how to change properties inside components, let's say I have the following component:

```
{
    props: {
        visible: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
         hide() {
              this.visible = false;
         }
    }
}
```

Although it works, it would give the following warning:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "visible" 
>   (found in component )

Now I'm wondering what the best way to handle this is, obviously the `visible` property is passed in when created the component in the DOM: `<Foo :visible="false"></Foo>`

Comment: Why yo you edit the prop? It should (code-wise) be controlled from one place, either from within the component og from a parent component? (You can do a combination by passing an update method as a prop, in your case the `hide()` could be on parent which then sends a reference to it as a prop).

Comment: @ArneHugo As you can see, the component itself has a method to basically "show/hide" an element. The parent can also update this property. Think of it as an alert message, the parent can control if it's visible, the component itself can remove itself.

Comment: Yes, I see that. My suggestion is to take props `visible` (boolean) and `hide`  (function). Then `hide` is defined on the parent, which also owns the state of `visible`. That way you don't edit props, but you edit the parent state, which is allowed.

Comment: Perhaps you can make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhb4rrjm/) to show what exactly you are doing, and I can change it to show you what I mean.

Comment: @ArneHugo i'll put together an example soon

Comment: @ArneHugo Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/4qj3e4bc/1/ - I understand what you're saying, but I don't think the parent should be responsible for the visibility of the component, every parent that wants to display an alert will have to implement this method. And I might want to hide an alert after x seconds, which means that every parent will need to implement this as well. I rather just have the component handle that.

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer, let me know if it did what you want.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Referencing the code in [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qj3e4bc/1/)

Somehow, you should decide on *one* place for the state to live, not two. I don't know whether it's more appropriate to have it just in the `Alert` or just in it's parent for your use case, but you should pick one.

### How to decide where state lives

Does the parent or any sibling component depend on the state?

- Yes: Then it should be in the parent (or in some external state management)
- No: Then it's easier to have it in the state of the component itself
- Kinda both: See below

In some rare cases, you may want a combination. Perhaps you want to give both parent and child the ability to hide the child. Then you should have state in both parent and child (so you don't have to edit the child's props inside child).

For example, child can be visible if: `visible && state_visible`, where `visible` comes from props and reflects a value in the parent's state, and `state_visible` is from the child's state.

I'm not sure if this is the behavour that you want, but here is a snippet. I would kinda assume you actually want to just call the `toggleAlert` of the parent component when you click on the child.

```js
var Alert = Vue.component('alert', {
  template: `
        <div class="alert" v-if="visible && state_visible">
        Alert<br> 
        <span v-on:click="close">Close me</span>
      </div>`,
  props: {
    visible: {
      required: true,
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      state_visible: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    close() {
      console.log('Clock this');
      this.state_visible = false;
    }
  }
});

var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  components: {
    'alert': Alert
  },
  data: {
    hasAlerts: false
  },
  methods: {
    toggleAlert() {
      this.hasAlerts = !this.hasAlerts
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.alert {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo" v-cloak>
  <alert :visible="hasAlerts"></alert>

  <span v-on:click="toggleAlert">Toggle alerts</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I totally get your point, but I feel this is quite common behaviour, no? Having all the logic in my parent component means having to copy/paste that logic over many different components that all use the `Alert`. You fiddle makes sense, and it seems for now that it is the best option.

Comment: What about for child components that are forms? Maybe you want to pass data from parent to the child, be able to edit it, and then if there is a successful post, pass the updated data back up to the parent?

Comment: @AllenWang in that case the data (and setters) can live in the parent, while the child implements the UI that the users interact with. The child does not need to own a copy of the data.

Comment: Even though you want the parent to have a definitive copy that wouldn't get changed unless there was a successful update in the child? Your point makes sense though, since if there is a complex structure of data and you only want to update one part of it, it's hard to get the logic of replacing the correct piece if you have to pass data.

Comment: @AllenWang If you need a copy of the data as it was before it was edited, I would do that outside of the components, in a store. That way the logic for keeping a copy lives in the store, and the components are easier to understand. Think of the original as the source of truth, and the copy as a draft. Then you can show the draft in edit mode and the truth in presentation mode.

Comment: @AllenWang But if you don't want to use a store, keep both the original data and the copy in the parent component, that way it's easy to understand where the data lives.

Comment: While I do get the sense of this, to me it feels just wrong. I want components so my code can be isolated. Doesn't seem a good ideia to have data outside the component. About stores, if it is a long list of child components each with its own child components in a deep tree, how to coordinate which child gets which part of the store data?? Again, there is some good sense in it, but it feels wrong all this for a trivial nesting of components

Comment: @Z.Khullah, sometimes you need to keep the data outside of the component. This is why we have the concept of controlled components. A controlled component may be purely presentational, or contain behavioral logic without maintaining its own state. It can even have some state of its own. Where you should keep the state depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I undesrtand and agree. Then I prefer stores rather than delegating to parent component that responsibility IMHO

Answer (score 8):

According to [the Vue.js component doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events):

> When the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around. So, how do we communicate back to the parent when something happens? This is where Vue’s custom event system comes in.

Use `$emit('my-event)` from the child to send an event to the parent. Receive the event on the child declaration inside the parent with `v-on:my-event` (or `@my-event`).

Working example:

```js
// child

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div><p>Child</p> <button @click="hide">Hide</button></div>',
  methods: {
    hide () {
      this.$emit('child-hide-event')
    }
  },
})

// parent

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    childVisible: true
  },
  methods: {
    childHide () {
      this.childVisible = false
    },
    childShow () {
      this.childVisible = true
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  border: solid 1px grey;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="box">
  <p>Parent | childVisible: {{ childVisible }}</p>
  <button @click="childHide">Hide</button>
  <button @click="childShow">Show</button>
  <p> </p>
  <child @child-hide-event="childHide" v-if="childVisible" class="box"></child>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

*If the prop is only useful for this child component*, give the child a `prop` like `initialVisible`, and a `data` like `mutableVisible`, and in the `created` hook (which is called when the component's data structure is assembled), simply `this.mutableVisible = this.initialVisible`.

*If the prop is shared by other children of the parent component*, you'll need to make it the parent's `data` to make it available for all children. Then in the child, `this.$emit('visibleChanged', currentVisible)` to notify the parent to change `visible`. In parent's template, use `<ThatChild ... :visibleChanged="setVisible" ...>`. Take a look at the guide: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Answer (score 5):

After a read of your latest comments it seems that you are concerned about having the logic to show/hide the alerts on the parent. Therefore I would suggest the following:

**parent**

```
# template
<alert :alert-visible="alertVisible"></alert>

# script
data () {
  alertVisible: false,
  ...
},
...
```

Then on the child alert you would $watch the value of the prop and move all logic into the alert:

**child (alert)**

```
# script
data: {
  visible: false,
  ...
},
methods: {
  hide () {
    this.visible = false
  },
  show () {
    this.visible = true
  },
  ...
},
props: [
  'alertVisible',
],
watch: {
  alertVisible () {
    if (this.alertVisible && !this.visible) this.show()
    else if (!this.alertVisible && this.visible) this.hide()
  },
  ...
},
...
```

Comment: updated to allow you to set a param on the parent to control any child alerts.

Comment: yeah one thing to bear in mind is you would only be using the param (alertVisible) on the parent to **set** the state, you wouldn't be able to reliably read from it. If you wanted to do this then you start requiring events or the passing of other method props (shown / hidden, etc) which the alert calls - but for the purpose of an alert it is unlikely the parent really needs to know its state, therefore it should work well most of the time with no additional logic. Also allows you to easily control multiple alerts from the parent which is a bonus.

Comment: I expect watch will work only first time. so in case of showing alert multiple times (which is usual case) this solution will not work. Otherwise parent still need a way to reset to original value (and know when)

Answer (score 2):

To help anybody, I was facing the same issue. I just changed my var that was inside v-model="" from props array to data. Remember the difference between props and data, im my case that was not a problem changing it, you should weight your decision.

E.g.:

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" fullscreen hide-overlay transition="dialog-bottom-transition">
```

Before:

```
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            any-vars: false
        }
    },
    props: {
            dialog: false,
            notifications: false,
            sound: false,
            widgets: false
        },
    methods: {
        open: function () {
            var vm = this;

            vm.dialog = true;
        }
    }
}
```

After:

```
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            dialog: false
        }
    },
    props: {
            notifications: false,
            sound: false,
            widgets: false
        },
    methods: {
        open: function () {
            var vm = this;

            vm.dialog = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it looks like on hack and violates the concept of a single data source, but its work)
This solution is creating local proxy variable and inherit data from props. Next work with proxy variable.

```
Vue.component("vote", {
    data: function() {
        return {
            like_: this.like,
            dislike_: this.dislike,
        }
    },

    props: {
        like: {
            type: [String, Number],
            default: 0
        },
        dislike: {
            type: [String, Number],
            default: 0
        },
        item: {
            type: Object
        }
    },

    template: '<div class="tm-voteing"><span class="tm-vote tm-vote-like" @click="onVote(item, \'like\')"><span class="fa tm-icon"></span><span class="tm-vote-count">{{like_}}</span></span><span class="tm-vote tm-vote-dislike" @click="onVote(item, \'dislike\')"><span class="fa tm-icon"></span><span class="tm-vote-count">{{dislike_}}</span></span></div>',

    methods: {
        onVote: function(data, action) {
            var $this = this;
            // instead of jquery ajax can be axios or vue-resource
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/api/vote/vote",
                data: {id: data.id, action: action},
                success: function(response) {
                    if(response.status === "insert") {
                        $this[action + "_"] = Number($this[action + "_"]) + 1;
                    } else {
                        $this[action + "_"] = Number($this[action + "_"]) - 1;
                    }
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    console.error(response);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

use component and pass props

```
<vote :like="item.vote_like" :dislike="item.vote_dislike" :item="item"></vote>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why it is missed by others when the warning has a hint

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or **computed property** based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "visible" (found in component )

Try creating a computed property out of the prop received in the child component as

```js
computed: {
  isVisible => this.visible
}
```

And use this computed in your child component as well as to emit the changes to your parent.

Comment: This is probably the simplest, most direct solution for the issue mentioned in the title. It's just annoying to have to maintain separate state for the initial and internal values, when they're tracking the same state.

Not sure why Vue didn't leave it up to the developer to say "I'm okay with mutating this state within the component once it's been set on initialization, and if another value is passed down to this component later, it's also fine if you overwrite the internal state I've set." Instead, we have to keep two copies of everything.