# public properties in vue.js showing warning

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5

**Component Code**

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="chat-users">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li v-for="chatuser in chatusers" class="left clearfix">
                {{ chatuser.UserName }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ["chatusers"],
        created() {
            axios.post("some url").then(response => {
                this.chatusers = response.data.Data;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<style>

</style>
```

Everything works perfectly, but I am getting below warning.

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
>   computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
>   "chatusers"

Comment: Do you need `chatusers` to be a prop? if not use `data` function instead of props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an explanation why prop should not be mutate in the vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components). If you need to mutate the state, perhaps you need a data instead.

Like:

```
    export default {
        data () { return { chatusers: null } },
        created() {
            axios.post("some url").then(response => {
                this.chatusers = response.data.Data;
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Vue.js data flow, the props received from parent should not be modified by child component. See [the official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props) and this Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40784502/5775077).

As suggested by your warning: "use a data or computed property based on the prop's value", that in your case is the response received from axios call.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best way to mutate the props, since the parent is in control of this data and any changes it will overwrite child data, [from the docs:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

> In addition, every time the parent component is updated, all props in
> the child component will be refreshed with the latest value. This
> means you should not attempt to mutate a prop inside a child
> component. If you do, Vue will warn you in the console.