# Something will trigger a warning in the console? Why is it not recommended and how would you fix it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

it's about good practice and knowledge on Javascript and VueJs.

I already commented the Type Api to see if other warnings persist

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "printer",
        props: {
            model: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            ip: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            jobs: {
                type: Object,
                validator: (value) => ["inProgress", "done", "error"].every((status) => typeof value[status] === "number")
    },
    progress: {
        type: Number,
            required: true
    },
    api: {
        type: Api,
            required: true
    }
    },
    data: () => ({
        timer: null
    }),
        methods: {
        async refreshProgress() {
            this.jobs = await this.api.getJobsNumbers({ model: this.model });
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.timer = setInterval(() => this.refreshProgress(), 30000);
    },
    destroyed() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
    };
</script>
```

So I'm looking for advices as I'm a beginner in VueJS and need to describe and purpose changements

Comment: What's the error you see in the console?

Comment: vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "model"

found in

---> <Printer> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "ip"

found in

---> <Printer> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "progress"

found in

---> <Printer> at src/App.vue
       <Root>

Comment: Update your question with part of the code (template) where you using your component....

Answer (score 0):

Question is missing exact warning text so I'm just guessing the warning you talk about is probably something like this:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "jobs"

In other words you are mutating parent's state in child component which is not a good idea and that's why Vue warns you.

There are several ways how to fix it:

1. make a copy of props and store it in components data. Update internal state only. Changes will not be visible to parent
2. Instead of mutating `jobs` prop, fire a custom event passing new state (returned from API call) as an argument. Parent needs to handle the event and update its own state with new value (update will flow through prop back to child component)
3. If you are absolutely sure your `printer` component will be the only place where `jobs` object will be mutated, you can mutate object's properties instead of replacing whole object without any warnings. This is possible but not recommended...

For more see [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) or some [very related SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780730/vue-js-changing-props)